# Page_Load not loaded after inheriting my own Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create BasePage Web.UI.Page that is inherited by my main page.
But when i create public class mypage : BasePage method Page_Load of this class is not loaded in page live cycle.
BasePage does not contain any Page_Load.
has anybody got a clue where can be the problem?
thanx

Answer (score 2):

1) Add class to your project

```
public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
}
```

2) Assuming that you want your `Default.aspx` page to inherit from `BasePage` class, modify `Default.aspx.cs` file in the following way:

```
public partial class _Default : BasePage  
{  
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {  
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();  
    }  
}
```

3) Do not change line `<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2._Default" %>` in your `Default.aspx` file.

4) Press F5 to start debugging. You will be asked to enable debugging in your `web.config` file. Press OK. You'll be stoped inside of `Page_Load` method, which means success.

Comment: I assume that you use ASP.NET 2.0 or higher.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your problem is that the event isn't actually called `Page_OnLoad` in the class, it's `OnLoad`.  Here's how you want your class to look:

```
public class MyPage : Page
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        // Your code

        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
}
```

[More detailed tutorial here](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020133935/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/041305-1.aspx).

Comment: @Josh, your answer gives incorrect information. You can call your event handling function whatever you like but in that case you need to add it as event handler explicitly. Or you can use predifined name Page_Load() that will be used automatically if AutoEventWireup is set to true. Not Page_OnLoad(), and not OnLoad(). See also link provided by Frederik Vig: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59t350k3%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: Roman, that code came from a working project...not sure how it can be incorrect given that.  The question is regarding an overloaded page class he's creating and why the base class's OnLoad isn't firing.  My suspicion is that this isn't a problem within his actual webpage, but the custom page class he's created.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I tested and it works. Please edit your answer (add one symbol for example). I'll change my vote.

Comment: No worries, thanks.  I probably should have included that link originally anyway for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the AutoEventWireup attribute is set to true. More information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59t350k3%28VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you override `OnLoad` on some of the classes and forget to call `base.OnLoad` then the `Load` event will not fire and consequently `Page_Load` will not be called either.

Answer (score 0):

Is your BasePage inhereting from  System.Web.UI.Page ?